# modifying $route templateUrl based on locale

Tags: angularjs, routes

I want to modify the templateUrl of a route definition, and make it dependant on the locale of the user.
E.g. '/views/en/faq.html' for English and '/views/fr/faq.html' for French users.
I have the locale stored in  the cookie *LOCALE*, but how can I access that cookie value in the templateUrl function, as $cookies is not available yet while running the config function?

Answer (score 1):

U can use angular translate service. This does this automatically. 
Link https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

Answer (score 0):

In your case make two state, and put in tamplateurl  `'/views/fr/faq.html'`  for frach and for  `'/views/en/faq.html'` for English

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('enFaq', {
      url: "/Faq",
      templateUrl: "/views/en/faq.html"
    })
    .state('frFaq', {
      url: "/Faq",
      templateUrl: "/views/fr/faq.html"
    })
});
```

Acccording your condition you can hide one state
like

```
 <a ui-sref="frFaq" ng-if="location=='fr'">Faq</a>
 <a ui-sref="enFaq" ng-if="location='en'">Faq</a>
```